# go install golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2@latest returns 'not a main package'

Tags: go, module, package

I'm new to go and am trying to run a go script that include the following:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/base64"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2"
)
```

If I try to run the script it appears that I am missing the pbkdf2 package:

```
$ go run DecryptGrafanaPassword.go
DecryptGrafanaPassword.go:12:2: no required module provides package golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

But when I try to install it it also complains that it isn't a main package:

```
$ go install golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2@latest                                                          
package golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2 is not a main package
```

What is the simplest way to get this running?

Comment: well, `golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2` isn't a `main` package. It looks like you want to add the dependency, in which case you use `go get golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2` or just `go mod tidy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`go install` dowloads a package and builds an executable. Every executable must have a submodule called `main`. Since `golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2` has no `main`, `go install` fails.

Actually, all you need is `go mod tidy`. It reads the source code, writes required modules to `go.mod` and downloads them. I created a tiny example with your imports and this is what `go mod tidy` done:

```
code$ go mod tidy
go: finding module for package golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2
go: downloading golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20220817201139-bc19a97f63c8
go: found golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2 in golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20220817201139-bc19a97f63c8
```

Here is `go.mod`, updated by this command:

```
module example.org

go 1.16

require golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20220817201139-bc19a97f63c8
```

The source code for `golang.org/x/crypto` was automatically downloaded to `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20220817201139-bc19a97f63c8/`

Comment: Every executable must have a *package* called `main`, *not* a submodule. You can only `go install` a `main` package.

Comment: Hmm maybe I have a more fundamental issue then as I also don't seem to have a mod file. `$ go mod tidy                                                                                           
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'` I'll have to see how to sort that out.

Comment: And go mod init seems to have issues also, maybe I didn't install it properly?
`$ go mod init                                                                                           1 ⨯
go: cannot determine module path for source directory /home/kali/Tools (outside GOPATH, module path must be specified)`

Comment: Somehow go it going ok, I think I wasn't clear on the purpose of the .mod file and not having one was causing a lot of issues.

Comment: @laurie sure, the first step, even before writing any code, should be `go mod init your/module/name`. It initialises `go.mod`.